# Perturabo's eye inside the eye

Tags: warhammer-40k

It is written that [Perturabo](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Perturabo) has always been able to see the [Eye of Terror](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Eye_of_Terror), no matter where he was.

> For as long as he remembered, no matter how many thousands of light years separated him from this particular Warp Storm, Perturabo was always aware of the Eye of Terror's presence and could perceive an echo of it on every world where he had looked to the heavens.

What does Perturabo see when he is at Warp or in the Eye of Terror itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation was described in *Angel Exterminatus* by Graham McNeill.

> Perturabo – master of siegecraft, and executioner of Olympia. Long has he lived in the shadow of his more favoured primarch brothers, frustrated by the mundane and ignominious duties which regularly fall to his Legion. When Fulgrim offers him the chance to lead an expedition in search of an ancient and destructive xenos weapon, the Iron Warriors and the Emperor's Children unite and venture deep into the heart of the great warp-rift known only as "the Eye". Pursued by a ragged band of survivors from Isstvan V and the revenants of a dead eldar world, they must work quickly if they are to unleash the devastating power of the Angel Exterminatus!
>
> Cover Description of the book, copied from [Lexicanum Article on Angel Exterminatus](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Angel_Exterminatus_(Novel))

It's quite a while since I've read the book but I cannot remember any mentioning of something being different with Perturabo. IIRC, no mentioning about the eye being closer or that he felt anything different as he entered the Eye of Terror. So, it would seem that it did not have any effect on him (or Graham McNeill simply forgot about it).